# Low degree cohomology of Eilenberg-MacLane space K(G,2)?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Recall that an Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(G, n)$ is characterized by $\pi_i(K(G,n)) = G$ if $i=n$ and is trivial otherwise.  (Of course $G$ should be abelian if $n>1$.)

I'm aware that computing $H^j(K(G,n), \mathbb Z)$ for general $j$ and $n$ is not so easy (see, e.g., [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24754/cohomology-of-the-eilenberg-maclane-spaces-kg-n)), but I'm hoping that for certain small values of $j$ and $n$ it's easier.

My question:  Is there a good reference for $H^j(K(G,2), \mathbb Z)$, where $j \le 4$ and $G$ is finite abelian (or just cyclic)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a finite cyclic group G, in the range you ask for you get cohomology groups
$$\mathbb{Z}, 0, 0, G \cong Ext(G, \mathbb{Z}), 0.$$
One sees this by for example computing the Leray--Serre spectral sequence for
$$K(G, 1) \to * \to K(G,2).$$

Comment: Are you sure about that last zero?

Comment: In cohomology? I think so: there is nothing that could kill it in the SS.

Comment: Where did all the Tor-terms from `$H_2(K(G,1),\mathbb{Z})$` go?

Comment: That group is zero when $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: Ah, shoot.  I didn't see that you were talking about the cyclic case.  My apologies!

Comment: For a low-dimensional calculation like this one can give a direct argument without using the spectral sequence.  When $G$ is cyclic, one can build a $K(G,2)$ with 3-skeleton consisting of a 3-cell attached to $S^2$ by a map of nonzero degree.  This forces $H_3$ to be zero.  Since one knows the homology groups are finite in positive dimensions, the universal coefficient theorem then gives $H^4=0$, and of course $H^3=H_2=G$. (The usual proof that the homology groups are finite uses spectral sequences, but tom Dieck's recent algebraic topology textbook gives a proof avoiding this.)

Comment: More generally for arbitrary abelian G and A we have $H^j(K(G,2);A) =$  $A$, 0, $Hom(G,A)$, $Ext(G;A)$, for $j = 0,1,2,3$ and $H^4(K(G,2);A) =$ the quadratic maps from G to A. This very classical and goes back to calculations of Whitehead and Mac Lane on classifying simply connected 2-types. You should especially look up Mac Lane's "Abelian Cohomology" which gives an explicit cocycle way of computing this. 